# Route to different port / app

Tags: javascript, localhost, port, href

My app is running on `https://localhost:1111/App/`

On click I want to route to another app / port running on

`https://localhost:2222/App/admin`

How do I accomplish this?

**Attempt**:

In my app (which runs on `localhost:1111`) I added `admin` to routes:

```
    routes = [

    {
        name: 'main',
        path: '/',
    },
    {
        name: 'login',
        path: '/login',
    },
    {
        name: 'admin',
        path: '/admin',
        ...
    },
]
```

However this routes to

```
https://localhost:1111/App/admin
```

Then I tried adding an `href` to the link

```
<li><a href="localhost:2222/App/admin" name="Admin"> ADMIN </a></li>
```

But this linked incorrectly:

```
https://localhost:1111/App/localhost:2222/App/admin
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `<li><a href="https://localhost:2222/App/admin" name="Admin"> ADMIN </a></li>`

Comment: Literally just did that as you answered. You can make an answer and I will mark it as the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<li><a href="https://localhost:2222/App/admin" name="Admin"> ADMIN </a></li>
```